# jQuery blur function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using html and jQuery library, trying to avoid core JavaScript, just bc I do not want to mix it

I have 3 fields, when user click on field1, then click some where else, I want field1 border to turn red only.

If user click on field2 then clicks some where else, I want field2 border to turn red only.

Right now `blur()` works perfectly but it creates a red border on every fields. this is because I am using .input class. any idea how can I do this without getting id? bc I will have 40 fields when i am done

**html code:**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="test1" class="input green" /> <br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="test2" class="input blue" />
```

**jquery code:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".input").blur(function() {
    if ($(".input").val().trim() == '')
      $(".input").css('border-color', 'red');
    else
      $(".input").css('border-color', '');
  });
});
```

Comment: Give the border a width and style too!! `.css('border','solid 1px red');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of repeating class name.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".input").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == '')
      $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    else
      $(this).css('border-color', '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input"/>
<input type="text" class="input"/>
<input type="text" class="input"/>
```

***Optional***

*Also instead of
`$(this).val().trim() == ''` you can use `$(this).val().length <= 0`*